# Чем заменить Kite для python на Atom?

Tags: python

Друзья, подскажите пожалуйста полному новичку чем можно заменить Kite для Python на Atom? На данный момент Kite недоступен для скачивания на офф сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Может будет достаточно jedi https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-python ?

Есть несколько синтаксических анализаторов без искуственного интелекта, но их достаточно для дополнения методов класса и разных функций из подключенных модулей.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/621707)

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics не хотелось писать воду. Ссылка на плагин от атом на странице плагинов атома. Перенести в тело ответа по сути то больше нечего.